# AAOS 13 RPI - no HDMI output

Tags: android, raspberry-pi4, hdmi, aaos

Hi I was following [this tutorial](https://www.snappautomotive.io/blog/android-automotive-os-13-on-a-raspberry-pi-4) step by step, but after flashing to a SD-Card the rainbow screen appeared for about a second. After that it just shuts off the HDMI with the "No Signal" text. However I can access the console by UART so I know it is booting.

My config.txt:

```ini
kernel=Image.gz
arm_64bit=1
dtparam=audio=on
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d-pi4,noaudio
#dtoverlay=dwc2,dr_mode=peripheral
initramfs ramdisk.img followkernel
enable_uart=1
disable_overscan=1
```

Also tried:

```ini
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode = 76
```

[The output from UART](https://pastebin.com/fcTdAWQ3)

Comment: You don't mention any details about the display connected but you may find more resources here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=hdmi+configuration

Comment: I was using old Hyunday TV(FHD) and Asus monitor(FHD) for the testing, both using micro-HDMI-HDMI cable

Comment: (Note, if you want to notify users about your new comments, add `@USER` to them.)